# Is there a standard way to parse a float using a custom decimal separator

Tags: java

I was wondering if there is a standard way in java to perform parsing over a floating point number. I don't mean `Float.parseFloat` I want to be able to provide the decimal separator manually, whether that's a comma or a point, please don't suggest hacks with Locale, 'cause that's silly . 
`java.text.NumberFormat` works with Locale and that's not I want. 
I was looking more along the lines of C# method `Convert.ToDouble` . Is there anything which resembles that. The method in C# allows to manually specify the decimal separator

Comment: Show us an example of what you want. I think it is not clear what you need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alternative 1: Replace "," with "." (as already suggested)

Alternative 2: Use DecimalFormat

```
    float value;
    DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat();
    DecimalFormatSymbols symbols = new DecimalFormatSymbols();
    symbols.setDecimalSeparator(',');
    df.setDecimalFormatSymbols(symbols);
    try {
        Number n = df.parse("1,234");
        value = n.floatValue();            
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Alternative 3: Use locale

Comment: Alternative 2 : That's exactly what I was looking for. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Locale is the sensible/supportable suggestion as you need to swap `,` and `.` in some cases.

If you want to use a different separator you can just do a text substitution. BTW Don't use `float` if you can help it as it has a low precision.

```
double d = Double.parseDouble(text.replace(MY_CHAR, '.'));
```

Comment: This solution is again dependent on the system Locale. What if point is not the decimal separator in the current Locale ?

Comment: @pmanolov You can find the Locale which matches the requirements of the user.